# Pivot table showing the Difference From a different column in the Previous year

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

If I have a pivot table from the below table...

```
+------+-------+--------+-------------+
| Year | Fruit | Actual | Requirement |
+------+-------+--------+-------------+
| 2020 | Apple | 10     | 11          |
+------+-------+--------+-------------+
| 2021 | Apple |        | 12          |
+------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

How would I calculate, for **2021 Apple**,  the difference between 2021 Requirement(12) and the 2020 Actual(10)?
IE: 12-10=2

(There are lots of other fruits in the actual table.)

EDIT: Considering the comment in the accepted answer, the title should have been: **Can you refer to a different field using the Pivot Table Field setting Show Data As?**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your data to a Table using Ctrl+T, then calculate the difference in your source data as a new column. You can then use the pivot on that field.

[image]

The formula:

```
=IFERROR([@Requirement]-XLOOKUP([@Year]-1&"-"&[@Fruit],[Year]&"-"&[Fruit],[Actual],""),"")
```

The important part here is getting the actual from the right row:

```
XLOOKUP([@Year]-1&"-"&[@Fruit],[Year]&"-"&[Fruit],[Actual],"")
```

Remember, the @ symbol represents the value in that column on the current row. So, get the year from the current row and subtract one to get the prior year. The concatenate it with a dash and the fruit on the current row. Use that string to look up "2020-Apple" in the array of values created by concatenating the Year and Fruit columns in the same way, then return the Actual from that row. If the current row is the first year for that fruit, the formula will return an error, so put "" as the last parameter of XLOOKUP.

Just subtract the ly Actual from the current year Requirement and Robert's your Mother's Brother.

Comment: sorry, can you not use one of the Pivot Table Field -> Show Data As  options to do this?

Comment: Not to refer to another field.

Comment: I had no idea that you could combine and look at multiple arrays in the lookup array parameter.  That's very cool.